# Swift 2 addObserver for specific UITextfield with object parameter

Tags: swift, swift2, textfield, nsnotification, addobserver

I'd like to call a function if a specific `UITextField` was tapped:
As far as I understand the following code works for notifications, which comes from the window:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

But I'd like to have a specific notification from a specific `UITextField`. I tried the following code without success:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: textField)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: textField)
```

I searched a lot and found that same question here ([Swift 2 addObserver for specific textField with the object parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082835/swift-2-addobserver-for-specific-textfield-with-the-object-parameter)), but the answers didn't work for me.

I'm trying that for 3 hours now.... Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look into `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol - there you could find solution to your problem. Just set your class as delegate, and implement one of methods of protocol. You can find them in documentation(for example `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`).
If you have any problems, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does UITextFieldDelegate provide the possibility to identify, if a specific textfield is tapped? E.g. I have five TextFields and I would like to call a specific function when only TextField number 4 and 5 is tapped? Thank you, Alex.

Comment: Yes, in argument of the method you get textField - so just write for example: ```if textField == passwordTextField {  }``` and so on ;)